# in the system contract, what is required for require_auth(_self)

Tags: smart-contract, authorization

In the system contract (eosio_system.cpp) there are some functions which require

```
require_auth( _self );
```

How is this auth level achieved by the 21 producers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The _self auth, shown here

```
require_auth( _self );
```

requires the authority of the owner of the contract, in this case eosio.  If we inspect that account with get account we see this

```
 owner     1:    1 eosio.prods@active
```

Which means eosio has given his authority to eosio.prods.  And if we inspect that account we see this.

```
active    15:    1 argentinaeos@active, 1 bitfinexeos1@active, 1 cypherglasss@active, 1 eos42freedom@active, 1 eosauthority@active, 1 eosbeijingbp@active, 1 eoscafeblock@active, 1 eoscanadacom@active, 1 eoscannonchn@active, 1 eosdacserver@active, 1 eosgenblockp@active, 1 eoshuobipool@active, 1 eosisgravity@active, 1 eosliquideos@active, 1 eosnewyorkio@active, 1 eosriobrazil@active, 1 eosstorebest@active, 1 eosswedenorg@active, 1 jedaaaaaaaaa@active, 1 teamgreymass@active, 1 zbeosbp11111@active,
```

Which means that the 21 BPs can do a multi-sig to sign for eosio.prods, which has delegated authority for eosio.

Comment: This is a high level answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `require_auth()` directive asserts that the transaction has been signed by the specified account.  In the case of `require_auth(_self)`, the assertion is that the transaction has been signed by the account that deployed the contract.  In other words, if you have deployed the contract to the `eosio` account, then the transaction has to be signed by the `eosio` account.

Comment: Thank you.  What is the mechanism by which the 21 BPs sign as eosio?

Comment: Generally, they don't.  They operate under their individual BP EOS accounts to sign the blocks.